# Why sum of squares is negative?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's consider very basic example:

```
import numpy as np
recon_x = ([int(x) for x in np.linspace(1, 12288, num = 12288)])
recon_x = np.array([recon_x]).reshape(-1, 12288)

x = ([int(x) for x in np.linspace(230, 13000, num = 12288)])
x = np.array([x]).reshape(-1, 12288)
```

I want to calculate the sum of squared differences between `x` and `recon_x`: I want to do this by code:

```
np.sum((x - recon_x) ** 2)
```

But it returns wrong result:

```
-1341621451
```

which of course is incorrect, since sum of squares cannot be negative. Do you see why it happens?

Comment: Arithmetic overflow. The  quantity is too big to fit into `numpy` int and overflows, in the process setting the sign bit.

Comment: Consider specifying the `dtype` of array so to avoid this. This is a good practice to avoid overflow and improve performance.

Comment: The fun thing is, since you're converting everything to a list of integers (before turning that into a NumPy array again), doing the last calculation in pure Python would get you the correct answer: `sum((item1 - item2)**2 for item1, item2 in zip(recon_x, x))` (remove the two lines with reshape), which is 2953345845, since Python can handle big integers.

Comment: Of course, `np.array([x]).reshape(-1, 12288)` seems very odd. Why not use `np.array(x)`? Better yet, why not use `x = np.linspace(1, 12288, num=12288, dtype=np.int64)` and remove the indirect conversion to integers and reshaping altogether?

Answer (score 1):

This an **overflow** issue. You can precise the type of the numpy arrays with `dtype` to be sure to use higher precision number format.

```
import numpy as np
recon_x = ([int(x) for x in np.linspace(1, 12288, num = 12288)])
recon_x = np.array([recon_x], dtype="float64").reshape(-1, 12288)

x = ([int(x) for x in np.linspace(230, 13000, num = 12288)])
x = np.array([x], dtype="float64").reshape(-1, 12288)
```